# Installing AppFabric on Windows Server Datacenter

Tags: cache, appfabric

we are running a virtual server with Windows Server Datacenter (32 bit) and I cannot install AppFabric on it.  When I run the executable downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2 I get the following error:

"Either the version of this package is not compatible with the version of windows you are running or this package is corrupt"

I am certain that our Windows Server Datacenter is backing on to Windows Server 2008 and I have installed SP2 with no problems.  Therefore, our server *should* be compatible as Windows Server 2008 SP2 is listed on the requirements above.

Has anybody else got it working with Datacenter?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Per the Additional Details section on the link you provided, make sure that you use the 6.0 version of AppFabric since you're running Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into this error when attempting to install on Windows 2008 SP2.  In addition to making sure you've downloaded the correct installer for your OS (6.0 for 2008/6.1 for 2008R2) ensure you have all prerequisite software installed per this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15848).  In my case, I was missing the IIS Web Deployment Tool.